# Clojure(Script) empty namespace

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

For an embedded DSL I'd like to remove all the core functions and require the ones I need one by one.
Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`:refer-clojure`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/refer-clojure) directive in your `ns` declaration to specify only the core functions you need:

```
(ns my-namespace
  (:refer-clojure :only [defn]))
```